# FirebaseError: "projectId" not provided in firebase.initializeApp

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-redux

I'm trying to run my first reactjs template  but i'm getting this error :

> FirebaseError: "projectId" not provided in firebase.initializeApp.

and i have no idea how it will run with firebase or without it

Comment: What do you mean with your first reactjs template? 

If you are trying reactjs for the first time I'd say go with documentation and a guide [how to start](https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html), but if you want to create a basic reactjs app you can use the [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app)

Answer (score 7):

I solved, with this:

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.4/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  // TODO: Replace with your project's customized code snippet
  var config = {
    apiKey: "<API_KEY>",
    authDomain: "<PROJECT_ID>.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "<PROJECT_ID>",
    storageBucket: "<BUCKET>.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "<SENDER_ID>",
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>
```

[Link help](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup?authuser=0#add_firebase_to_your_app)

Comment: Looks like this approach exposes sensitive data.

Answer (score 0):

Added the automatic initialization scripts to index.html. Works for local dev running the app with **npm start**. Should also work when deployed to firebase.

```
<body>
 <div id="root"></div>
 <script src="/__/firebase/7.19.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
 <script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
</body>
```

In the sources, I initialized firebase passing only projectId.

```
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp({
  projectId: '<PROJECT_ID>'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the same and decided to force it:

```
import {initializeApp} from 'firebase/app';
import {getFirestore} from 'firebase/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = JSON.parse(
    process?.env?.FIREBASE_CONFIG ?? '{}',
);

const app = initializeApp({...firebaseConfig, projectId: firebaseConfig?.projectId});
```

In my case, I was converting my config json from its string form (JSON.parse).

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same Error.
Solution and cause of the problem are:

**Cause**
in official Firebase documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/module-bundling?hl=en&authuser=0) you may see the following line:
const firebaseApp = initializeApp({ /* config */ });

You may copy it and paste in your project replacing the commented part "/* config */" - and this will work,

***but if you have*** declared your configurations as a variable earlier like this:

var firebaseConfig = {
apiKey: "API_KEY",
authDomain: "PROJECT_ID.firebaseapp.com",
databaseURL: "https://DATABASE_NAME.firebaseio.com",
projectId: "PROJECT_ID",
...
};

**Solution:**
you must **erase the curly brackets** as well.

It is a kinda dumb error but if you don't catch it right away you loose quite a time finding the cause of the error.